# Kal calendar fetching data from calendar in simulator but not on device

Tags: objective-c, ios, github, calendar, ios-simulator

I am trying to implement the Kal calender into my own project. I've downloaded a copy of the github project and run it on the simulator. Everything works correctly and is showing data from the simulator calendar.

But when I test it on a real device. It is not fetching data and it gives me the following error.

```
CalendarApp[1024:1103] Predicate call to calendar daemon failed: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1013 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (EKCADErrorDomain error 1013.)"
```

This is how my fetch looks like.

```
- (void)presentingDatesFrom:(NSDate *)fromDate to:(NSDate *)toDate delegate:(id<KalDataSourceCallbacks>)delegate
{
  // asynchronous callback on the main thread
  [events removeAllObjects];
  NSLog(@"Fetching events from EventKit between %@ and %@ on a GCD-managed background thread...", fromDate, toDate);
  dispatch_async(eventStoreQueue, ^{
    NSDate *fetchProfilerStart = [NSDate date];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:fromDate endDate:toDate calendars:nil];
    NSArray *matchedEvents = [eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      NSLog(@"Fetched %d events in %f seconds", [matchedEvents count], -1.f * [fetchProfilerStart timeIntervalSinceNow]);
      [events addObjectsFromArray:matchedEvents];
      [delegate loadedDataSource:self];
    });
```

Can anybody help me?

Kind regards and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it had something to do with users permissions. I found my answer over here.

[How to get the name/id of default calendar in iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754064/how-to-get-the-name-id-of-default-calendar-in-ios-6)