# Having app restart itself when it detects change to privacy settings

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have an app that uses the `ALAssets` framework to access to the users photo library. I wrote some code that detects whether or not the app has permission to access the photo library, and if it doesn't, I display an alert message which tells the user to turn on location services for the app in settings.

Problem is, when the user manually changes the privacy settings and then they reopen the app, iOS forces the app to crash with SIGKILL.

I've noticed that the way another app handles this is by somehow detecting a change in the privacy settings, and forcing the app to restart the next time the user opens it. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You misunderstand what is happening. Your app is not crashing (though it may appear so if you are running the app with the debugger).

When you switch to the Settings app (and your app is suspended in the background) and change the privacy settings, suspended apps are terminated. When you switch back to your app, it is simply started again. This is no different than your app being killed for any other reason.

It is up to you to code your app to handle this by restoring its previous state. The other app you talk about is simply returning the user to the previous state. Many apps do this. It has nothing to do with being killed due to privacy changes. The app would restore state when being killed for any reason.

Comment: Thank you. When I was running the app from xCode, like you say, it appeared like it was freezing. But when I run the app just off of the phone, and then change the settings, the app reboots itself the next time it starts instead of freezing.

Comment: Is this specific to the Simulator? I tried changing the Twitter access on a device and it didn't cause my Twitter app to be killed. It came back from background as usual.

Comment: @CoDEFRo When debugging through Xcode, you need to click the Stop button after the app crashes, then you can properly restart the app.

Comment: Right...in this instance it makes sense why it would freeze, because iOS is trying to restart it, but it's still connected to the debugger. Thanks again!

Comment: @rmaddy Please add Apple documentation