# App killed when privacy settings changed

Tags: ios, swift, camera, privacy

My app is getting crashed when privacy(camera) settings changed.

In the console getting this message

**Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9**

But checked many apps like skype and whats app in the same device, they are not crashing.

**how the crash happens**

1. First when asking the permission for camera  allow/don't allow
2. keep the app in background
3. go to settings of app and change the permission

According to this([Toggling Privacy settings will kill the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522574/toggling-privacy-settings-will-kill-the-app)) there is no way around for this.

1.How to fix this issue?

2. if there is no way how other apps are not restarting?

Thank you..

Comment: Can u please check my updated question

Comment: I have added another reference. From [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15930922/1187415): *"It is up to you to code your app to handle this by restoring its previous state. ..."*

Comment: so there is no way to avoid restart ?

Comment: Look at the answer provided, http://stackoverflow.com/a/15930922/5716449
When the privacy settings are changed, your app is terminated and simply reboots. If you want to save the current state or data or whatever just write some handling in the didEnterBackground in your app delegate and when the app is restarted you can go back to the last state it was in.