# How to prevent ios app kill when changing camera settings in iOS.

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

In privacy settings, when I change the permissions related to iOS app (Camera or Microphone) and again back to the app then app restarting from initial state and I lost my existing state of work in the app.

Is there any way to save the last state or avoid killing/restart ?

Comment: "*Is there any way to avoid killing/restart ?*" - No.

Comment: Yok can use UserDefault to save last state of camera. Then you can get the state from UserDefaults to set the camera again.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [applicationWillTerminate(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate) method. this will be called before Your app is killed and there is no way to stop it from restart when privacy permission is changed

Also take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15930922/2299040)