# UIViewController dismiss after camera permission updated in Settings

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, camera

im redirecting the user to Settings if camera access isn't allowed and user profile page dismiss when the camera permission changed.

[image: UIViewController dismiss after camera permission updated in Settings]

1. On tap Go to Settings option to change permission settings
2. After Camera permission value change
3. When on tap previous app button(?) on status bar
4. Current `UIViewController` dismiss and it goes to previous `UIViewController` which is rootViewController

How to prevent this situation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Having app restart itself when it detects change to privacy settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930708/having-app-restart-itself-when-it-detects-change-to-privacy-settings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at that answer: [Having app restart itself when it detects change to privacy settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930708/having-app-restart-itself-when-it-detects-change-to-privacy-settings/15930922#15930922)

The app restarts and you can't prevent this. You can preserve and restore the state: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PreservingandRestoringState.html

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2**

- According to [V D Purohit's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53101325/uiviewcontroller-dismiss-after-camera-permission-updated-in-settings?noredirect=1#comment93098634_53101325), the app restarts itself. But
  the link he shared doesn't show how to prevent this situation.
- Thanks [@messeb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53101547/8676854) for the [Preserving and Restoring State](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PreservingandRestoringState.html)
  article.
- [And here is a State Restoration Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1395-state-restoration-tutorial-getting-started)

> If you have a form in your app and if you might need a permission
> change in your app you should store&restore the data. Because your app
> might restart after a permission change (camera usage permission for
> example).

**Step 1:** Add Restoration IDs to your `UIViewController`s from Identity Inspector on your storyboard.

**Step 2:** Add these methods to AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldSaveApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldRestoreApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

**Step 3:** Override these methods in your `UIViewController`. Your data will stored in `encodeRestorableState` method. And they get restored in `decodeRestorableState` method.

```
override func encodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
    coder.encode(self.myTextField.text ?? "", forKey: "myTextFieldRestorationKey")
    super.encodeRestorableState(with: coder)
}

override func decodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
    if let txt = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "myTextFieldRestorationKey") as? String { self.myTextField.text = txt }
    super.decodeRestorableState(with: coder)
}
```