# iOS app crashes when switched to settings and microphone access is granted

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, microphone

Not sure, which piece of my code to publish here. My app requires microphone access to work. It asks for mic permission in the beginning. During testing, I gave permission but then went in to settings and revoked the permission.

Then I run the app and then switch to settings and turn mic access 'On' for my app, the app crashes.

Can anyone tell me what is invoked in the app when the access is granted, so I can fix it?

Comment: The duplicate is about the Contacts permission but the issue applies to all of the various permission such as Photos, Microphone, etc.

Comment: There're certain permissions that cause the app to be *restarted* when changed. Camera, camera roll and microphone are one of them. Have a look at [App killed by SIGKILL when changing privacy settings](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12652502/593709)

Comment: Thanks guys, it seems the same issue as described in other questions you mentioned.