# iOS Application does not return to same View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, avfoundation

I am using Camera in my application. I check for camera permission and if the camera permission is not enabled I show a dialog asking the user to go to settings.

If the user accepts I redirect to Settings page. Here 2 cases occur -

1) If the user accepts the dialog and goes to settings page but does not enable camera permission but clicks Back(with App Name, not the Back on Settings Navigation Bar) the view controller which redirected to Settings is shown.

2) If the user enables the camera permission and clicks back, the Home View Controller of the app is shown.

I want to show the view controller which redirected to Settings in both the cases.

I have the below code in my View Controller but still this function is not called in the 2nd case.

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActive) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];`

I am using Objective-C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When user changes the app `Settings`, the OS automatically kills the app. That's why your app launches when you click back in 2) but not 1)

[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652502/app-killed-by-sigkill-when-changing-privacy-settings)

To simulate restoration after coming back,

1) Add a `UserDefaults` value with the name of the active `UIViewController` before leaving
2) On `appDidFinishedLaunching` redirect to it.

Comment: Then how do I detect that and go the required View Controller?