# How to Change camera permission from application in ios swift

Tags: xcode

I try to change camera permission.

But after changing permission it never go back to application.

iphone device force to restart application.

How I can do this.

Comment: We need to guess your code. Wait, that's not the code we're guessing for!

Comment: how i can store current state of application. for after click on back app must be on same screen

Comment: I give up. I can't explain `code`.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the user changes the privacy settings like camera permission, the app will get killed by `SIGKILL`. That is the reason for your device force to restart your application.

Check this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652502/app-killed-by-sigkill-when-changing-privacy-settings) for more info.

There is no straightforward way to come back to our app from settings app.In case if you want to restore the app state, we need to save the user state before the app gets killed and when restarts check for any previous pending state and restore it.

Comment: thanks, but i don't have any idea how to restore ui when apps in background.